# How to prevent sending of emails using event Enlight_Components_Mail_Send?

Tags: shopware

Is there a way to tell shopware not to send email inside of function called by event "Enlight_Components_Mail_Send"?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to deprecate all emails in shopware or certain?

If you want to deprecate all emails in shopware you need to add into
`SHOPWARE_ROOT/config.php`

```
<?php return array (
  'db' => 
  array (
    'host' => 'YOU_HOST',
    'port' => 'YOU_PORT',
    'username' => 'YOU_USER',
    'password' => 'YOU_PASS',
    'dbname' => 'YOU_DATABASE',
  ),
  'mail' =>
  array(
     'type' => 'file',
  )
);
```

In this case mail will be saved as file instead of sending via SMTP.