# Deactivate sending of certain mails in Shopware 5

Tags: php, shopware

For a shop we need to deactivate most of Shopware's default mails, such as order confirmation, bill, etc. The only ones we need to keep are the ones about user management (profile created, forget password).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291801/how-to-prevent-sending-of-emails-using-event-enlight-components-mail-send) that shows how to disable all mails.

But nothing else, searched SO, Shopware forum (German and English), a lot of people having the same need but no solution posted anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deactivate the order confirmation email in backend using the "send order mail" field under the checkout settings like described in the [documentation](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-5-en/settings/checkout).

Most of the other emails are triggered manually on e.g. order status change or cron jobs.

Comment: And how can I deactivate all the other mails that are "triggered manually"?

Comment: @kero Yo can try to remove the sender, name, plain and html content of an email template as suggested [here](https://forum.shopware.com/discussion/60563/status-mails-einzeln-aktivieren-deaktivieren), but I didn't try it.

Comment: I only got the project handed over to me, your answer did help. But we will not investigate further if and how disabling of other mails is still possible. Thanks :)